# Refer table filed that belong to multiple tables

Tags: magento

I am trying to get all the products that have sold the most within a window of time. I am using the following query

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
         ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
    ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
```

However created_at is a field in more than one table. How to correctly refer to the field from the table I intend to. I would also like to filter using the field from the intended table.

Answer (score 0):

The query will look like this

```
SELECT ...... FROM `sales_flat_order_item` AS `order_items` INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `order` ON `order`.entity_id = order_items.order_id AND `order`.state <> 'canceled' LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` .....
```

So you have the tables aliases

order_items, order , and e

So you can add order like this

```
$productCollection->getSelect()->order('order_items.created_at' . ' ' . 'DESC');
```